# SQL Distinct keyword

Tags: sql, keyword

I would be thankful if someone could help me categorize the word Distinct. I am learning sql and understand what it does but is it a function, an attribute or a keyword just like SELECT, FROM and WHERE etc. I guess it to be a keyword and in which case what does it mean to write two keywords together (i.e SELECT DISTINCT <*tuple of attributes*> FROM <*relation*>)?

Comment: I think your applying the classification of identifiers etc. from one style of language to another. This generally does not work. In SQL much of this is simply "that is the syntax" (eg. consider `inner join` vs. `left outer join`: both do one thing but use multiple words).

Comment: Indeed I am trying to classify reserved keyword used by sql from the very beginning. Thereby I intend to look at fairly complicated, long and compositional queries in particular later and decompose it into subparts and understand it better. Just like one can do with sentences in English by understanding what particular parts of speech are.

Answer (score 1):

It is a keyword and could be used in different contexts:

```
Select distinct field1, field2, field3
from myTable;
```

Within this context the returned data has only 1 row per each distinct values of field1, field2 and field3 column values. ie:

field1, field2, field3

```
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 1
```

with distinct would return:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 1
```

IOW it is like group by on all fields included in select.

It is also used with aggregations like this:

```
Select count(distinct productId)
from OrderDetails;
```

Would count each productID only once within the group (here in example didn't add any special grouping). Above query for example would answer a question like how many of our products had any sale so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of searching and found it is called :
Conditional expressions : DISTINCT **predicate**.
Not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think thats what I was looking for. Now can Google for other conditional expressions or predicate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a keyword, used primarily in two contexts:

- `SELECT DISTINCT`
- `COUNT(DISTINCT . . .)`

In some databases, it is also allowed with set-functions, such as `UNION DISTINCT`.  This highlights the default behavior of the set-function (which removes duplicates).

Conceptually, it modifies the action to work only on distinct values.

It can be used with other aggregation functions, but that usage is not useful.  It usually implies a problem with the data, usually a data modeling problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the language it is a keyword, but note that at the core, those language keywords serve to denote invocations of operators ("relational" operators, though pseudo-relational is really more accurate) and operators ***are*** functions ...

So there is a bit of a case to say that it serves both purposes, and that the distinction you are asking about is actually rather irrelevant.

examples

SELECT ... : invocation of "bag" projection / SELECT DISTINCT ... : invocation of "relational" projection.

WHERE a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b : the "more relational" equality operator (that yields true if both a and b are null) / WHERE a = b : the "less relational" equality operator (that yields false if both a and b are null).